# How to change value in typedef enum?

Tags: objective-c

I have the next `enum`:

```
typedef enum {
    SignUp,
    LogIn
} TypeAction;
```

and after property in interface:

`@property (assign, nonatomic) TypeAction * typeAction;`

In button action I do:

```
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender {
    self.typeAction = SignUp;
}
```

So, in another button action I try to compare as:

```
 - (IBAction)Check:(id)sender {
        if(self.typeAction = SignUp){
          //       
        }
    }
```

But I get `nil in`self.typeAction`

Comment: You need `==`, not `=`.  Also, `SignUp` will have a value of zero, which is the same as `nil`.

Comment: your property also shouldn't be a pointer

Comment: Yeah this code should be showing all kinds of warnings/errors. Is this the code you actually have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably be:

```
 - (IBAction)Check:(id)sender {
        if(self.typeAction == SignUp){
          //       
        }
    }
```

or, actually, you might want to change the `if`-statement to `if(SignUp == self.typeAction)`, because the compiler would catch the `==` problem.

And your property declaration should be:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) TypeAction typeAction;
```

`assign`s are not pointers, and you were setting `self.typeAction` to `SignUp` in that line of the `if` statement, which is then read as `nil` because it was seeing `self.typeAction` as a pointer, which is what was causing the error.

Comment: Thank you, will try. How I can display via NSlog current typeAction?

Comment: When I try to use `if(self.typeAction == LogIn){
          //       
        }` It gives me alert

Comment: Help me please, where I may to init default `self.typeAction`?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` for a UIViewController class, `awakeFromNib` in a UIView instantiated from IB. Depends on what kind of class you have.

Comment: What @EmilioPelaez said. Also, if you don't initialize it, it will be `SignUp` (or `0`) by default, since it is handled as an `unsigned int` under the hood.